# Why is the SSID from getConfiguredNetworks() added quotation mark?

Tags: android

I hope to get both the name of current connected WIFI and the name of stored connected WIFI.

I find wifiInfo.getSSID() can get the correct result, such as MyWiFi1,

but the name from config.SSID is added quotation mark, such as "MyWiFi2".

How can I get correct name from config.SSID? Thanks!

```
public static List<MWiFi> ListPhoneStoredWiFi(Context context) {
    List<MWiFi> myWiFiList= new ArrayList<MWiFi>();
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 

    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo!=null){
        if (wifiInfo.getNetworkId()!=-1){
           MWiFi mWiFi=new  MWiFi();
           mWiFi.name=wifiInfo.getSSID();
           mWiFi.networkID=wifiInfo.getNetworkId();
           mWiFi.enabled=true;
           myWiFiList.add(mWiFi);
        }
    }

    // List stored networks
    List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if (configs!=null){     
      for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
          if (config.networkId!=wifiInfo.getNetworkId()) {
             MWiFi mWiFi=new  MWiFi();
             mWiFi.name=config.SSID;
             mWiFi.networkID=config.networkId;
             mWiFi.enabled=true;                 
             myWiFiList.add(mWiFi);
          }
      }
    }   

    return myWiFiList;      
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for [WifiConfiguration.SSID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#SSID) and [WifiInfo.getSSID()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID()), you should always expect those values to come back in quotes when they represent UTF-8 encoded strings. This is to differentiate them from SSID's that are returned as a string of hexadecimal digits...which is also a value you should expect to handle.

Since the framework tells you to expect the variation, your code ought to handle finding and masking out quote characters.

Comment: With an important caveat that I learned recently -- apparently on Android 4.1 and below, even though the documentation says it will, it will return the SSID *without* surrounding quotes. Best to check for and strip out the edge quotes from the result and then compare.

Comment: What if my SSID starts end ends with quotes? Are they somehow escaped?