# Android's WifiInfo#getSSID(): is there a way to understand if SSID has double quotes by itself or is it Android created ones?

Tags: android, android-wifi, ssid

According to documentation of the `getSSID` method:

> Returns the service set identifier (SSID) of the current 802.11 network. If the SSID can be decoded as UTF-8, it will be returned surrounded by double quotation marks. Otherwise, it is returned as a string of hex digits. The SSID may be {@code null} if there is no network currently connected.

Source code of this method does somewhat conform to the documentation (except of `null` case), so I won't attach it here as a code snippet, [but here it is for API 21](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-21/blob/master/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.java).

It seems I can just remove double codes, but according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522594/why-is-the-ssid-from-getconfigurednetworks-added-quotation-mark), `getSSID()` method of `WifiInfo` it can be said that **implementation can vary between android versions**.

Casual sources about SSID mention that it is **alphanumeric**, but I found a controversial statement: according to [this source](https://bttn.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000529141-firmware-201412-wi-fi-ssid-and-password-cannot-have-spaces-or-special-characters), **SSID can contain double quotes**, so it is a valid character.

As a result, **UTF-8 encoded SSID can either be wrapped with double quotes or not to be**.

Question: is here a **reliable** way to identify if SSID contain double quotes at both the end and the start, or it comes from android's `getSSID` implementation?

Answer (score 3):

WifiInfo.getSSID() returns String so you can use String.matches and String.replace for this

To detect:

```
String ssid = "\"MYSSID\"";
Boolean matches = ssid.matches("^\".*\"$");
Log.v("Check quotes", "Matching " + matches);
```

To remove:

```
ssid = ssid.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: Please note If the SSID itself contain double quote in the middle you will remove it too.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution in `Kotlin` would be something like this

```kotlin
ssid = ssid.removeSurrounding("\"")
```

which will take care of removing the leading and trailing double quotes if they were found.